# Assembly ARM cmp operator

Tags: assembly, arm

I've searched around and have found no answer to this, I'm using cmp to compare 2 values which I know should be the same because they appear to be the same when I print them. However, for some reason assembly doesn't consider them to be the same. I'm very new to assembly and all I can figure out is that it might have something to do with the registers I'm using.

```
ldr x19, [x0, x_offset] 
ldr x21, [x1, x_offset]
cmp x19,x21 
b.ne returnResult
```

In the above code it will always take the break point. I know that x19 = x21 because I printed those values out. Perhaps it's checking the address?

```
fmtTest:.string "First value is : %d, Second value is : %d\n"
.balign 4

define(printf, `    
adrp    x0, $1  
add x0, x0, :lo12:$1    
bl  `printf'')

mov x1, x19
mov x2, x21
printf(fmtTest)
```

Comment: Print how? Maybe you are only printing 32 bits but loaded and compare 64. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I've been using this print function


define(printf, `
 adrp x0, $1
 add x0, x0, :lo12:$1
 bl `printf'')

Comment: Yeah, %d only prints 32 bits, so the top 32 bits may be different.